# Django Field Error Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: companytype, contactno, contactperson, id, jobs, user

Tags: django

I receive this error While am execute the project

> FieldError at /accounts/EmpReg/
>   Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: companytype, contactno, contactperson, id, jobs, user

*views.py*

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('e-mail address'), blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)
    companyname = models.CharField(_('companyname'), max_length=50)
    usertype = models.CharField(_('usertype'), max_length=30)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(_('superuser status'), default=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), default=timezone.now)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, verbose_name=_('groups'),blank=True)
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(Permission,verbose_name=_('user permissions'), blank=True)


class RegistrationProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    key_generated = models.DateTimeField()
    objects = RegistrationManager()
```

*forms.py*

```
class EmpRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput)
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    usertype = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    companyname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
    companytype = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PREFERRED_COMPANYTYPE, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    contactno = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
    contactperson = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
    tos = forms.BooleanField()
```

*views.py*

```
def empreg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmpRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(user__username=form.cleaned_data['username'],password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],email=form.cleaned_data['email'],)
            user.companyname = form.cleaned_data['companyname']
            user.usertype = form.cleaned_data['usertype']
            user.save()
            e=EmployerReg_Form(user=user, companytype=form.cleaned_data['companytype'],contactno=form.cleaned_data['contactno'],contactperson=form.cleaned_data['contactperson'])
            e.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/EmpReg_Complete/')
else:
    form = EmpRegistrationForm()
    return render_to_response('registration/empregform.html', { 'form': form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

*models.py*

```
class EmployerReg_Form(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    companytype = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    contactno = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contactperson = models.CharField(max_length=30)

PREFERRED_COMPANYTYPE = (
('Company', 'Company'),
('Consultancy', 'Consultancy'),
)
```

please check the above code and help where I do mistake

Comment: What is an `EmployerReg_Form` and how does it look?

Comment: EmployerReg_Form is a model, now I updated

Comment: There is still something missing. The relevant model isn't included in your question...

Comment: I cleared above error. Please give answer for this.  I'm storing both employer and jobseeker details in same User table. I have differentiate both details using field usertype(usertype=employer/jobseeker). While login after authentication it should be redirected to dashboard depends on their usertype. if user is jobseeker it should be redirected to one dashboard else user is employer it should be redirected to another dashboard page. Please help me

Comment: I would advise you to try it yourself, and start a new topic on this. To get you starting, please read this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests "How to log a user in" In the login view: q = User.objects.get(username=username) Then it is as easy as if q.usertype == 'employer' redirect to .... if q.usertype == 'jobseeker': redirect to....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part you are calling EmployerReg_Form:

```
e=EmployerReg_Form(
         user=user,
         companytype=form.cleaned_data['companytype'],
         contactno=form.cleaned_data['contactno'],
         contactperson=form.cleaned_data['contactperson']
  )
```

When you look at the model you will see that the user field is a Foreignkey to model User. If you know the ID EmployerReg_Form should be mapping to User your line would be:

```
e=EmployerReg_Form(
         user__ID=user, 
         companytype=form.cleaned_data['companytype'],
         contactno=form.cleaned_data['contactno'],
         contactperson=form.cleaned_data['contactperson']
  )
```

Mapping to a name would be something like this:

```
e=EmployerReg_Form(
         user__username=user, 
         companytype=form.cleaned_data['companytype'],
         contactno=form.cleaned_data['contactno'],
         contactperson=form.cleaned_data['contactperson']
  )
```

Note the double underscore after user.

Oh, and shouldn't the User model be in your models.py instead of views.py?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm storing both employer and jobseeker details in same User table. I have differentiate both details using field usertype(usertype=employer/jobseeker). While login after authentication it should be redirected to dashboard depends on their usertype. if user is jobseeker it should be redirected to one dashboard else user is employer it should be redirected to another dashboard page. Please help me.